# Treemap FirstKey() importing error

Tags: java, treemap

I am trying to use the firstKey() method for my treemap (memory).
My code looks like:

```
import java.util.*;

//Code in the middle.

System.out.println(memory.firstKey());
```

It however gives me this error:

```
GameLogic.java:276: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method firstKey()
location: interface java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Character>
System.out.println(memory.firstKey());
                                     ^
```

All advice appreciated. The same error happens if I use lastKey() as well.

Comment: Please provide full code

Comment: @Prasad Kharkar The inbetween code has nothing to do with this. It relates to other stuff. There's also a lot, too much to put on here.

Comment: I want to see how you have instantiated the map.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have declared

```
Map map = new TreeMap();
```

you need to instead do

```
TreeMap map = new TreeMap(); //OR SortedMap map = new TreeMap() 
map.firstKey();
```

Because `firstKey()` is a method which exists in `TreeMap` which is not defined in `Map` contract (or interface)

Comment: `SortedMap map = new TreeMap()` should be sufficient here

Comment: thanks @Marco13 .. I was searching for the interface which had that method

Answer (score 2):

`firstKey` method is not defined in [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface so `map#firstKey` creates compilation error. This method is defined in [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Recommended would be -

```
SortedMap smap = ...; 
smap.firstKey();
```

or else

```
System.out.println((SortedMap)memory.firstKey());
```

or

```
System.out.println((TreeMap)memory.firstKey());
```